# How do I move the workspace switcher/selector in Activities overview to the left in GNOME?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, workspace-switcher, activities-overview

Is there any way of moving the workspace overview in *Activities* to the left side of the screen? I've tried looking for extensions and going through the GNOME Tweak tool, but without success.

[image]

Having used other DEs in the past (Unity, Xfce, KDE), I am used to efficiently moving the pointer around the top left corner of the screen only, and find it quite annoying to have to move all the way to the middle right to select a workspace, after launching Activities using the hot corner on the top left.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using the **[Workspaces to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/)** GNOME extension. From the extension's preferences, set "Left" for the '*Show the dock at the following screen position*' option in the *General* tab.

[image]

To disable the dock-like feature, disable both auto-hide and intellihide options in the *Behaviour* tab.

To learn more about installing and configuring GNOME shell extensions, refer to [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530)

Comment: I can confirm this works, but sadly the grid representation of "Workspace Grid" is lost. I like havig a 2x2 workspace arrangement. Any way of integrating both extensions?

Comment: As this is not currently possible, I deleted that specification from the question and selected your answer as solving the original issue.

Comment: Custommisation seems to be in development: https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid/pull/67?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Answer (score 0):

Install one of the many `workspaces` GNOME extensions found [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

I personally like [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/943/workspace-scroll/) one... Workspace Scroll. It lets you change workspaces by pointing anywhere in the top panel, and rolling your mouse wheel.